# Restoring database into SQL Server in a docker

Tags: sql-server, docker, database-restore

I have a SQL Server instance running in docker on OSX. I have connected to it with SSMS to create an empty target database, but now I need to restore the backup to that empty target database.

How is that done?  Do I mount a new volume to the container?  Do I copy the backup into the container?  I have tried a few things and nothing is working.

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/2020/03/15/attaching-restoring-databases-inside-a-container

Comment: @AaronBertrand, thank you.  Your email got me thinking and I found this link from Microsoft that had answers I was looking for: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/tutorial-restore-backup-in-sql-server-container?view=sql-server-2017